# How to get data of last 7 days from last friday in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to get data of last 7 days starting from Friday. I tried almost every query but its not working. It returns only one day. Can someone help me ? Here is my query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ticketlogs.dcid, COUNT(*) AS `count` 
  FROM ticketlogs 
 WHERE dcid = $dcid
   AND DATE(ticketdate) = 
       DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(),
                   INTERVAL ((7 + WEEKDAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
                                                         - 4) % 7) DAY), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: your code is **vulnerable** to **sql injection** so please use only **prepared statements with parameters**

Comment: I just want to learn how to get the data i need. Of course i will change my code.

Comment: don't forget to use `GROUP BY` clause along with aggregation function please(in this case,`DISTINCT` will be redundant of course)

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried to use `GROUP BY` but its still returns empty. Am i wrong here ?

`SELECT ticketlogs.dcid, COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM ticketlogs 
 WHERE dcid = "654791825424515093"
   AND DATE(ticketdate) = 
       DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(),
                   INTERVAL ((7 + WEEKDAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
                                                         - 4) % 7) DAY), '%Y-%m-%d') GROUP BY ticketlogs.dcid`

Comment: please provide a [mre] so that we can help you

Comment: Do you mean getting the data set for the interval starting from last friday upto next thursday(7days) ?

Answer (score 1):

The previous Friday ends at:

```
(case when dayofweek(now()) = 7 then curdate() - interval 1 day
      when dayofweek(now()) = 6 then curdate()
      else dayofweek(now()) - interval dayofweek(now()) day
 end)
```

You can incorporate this into your logic.  I would use:

```
select t.*
from ticketlogs tl cross join
     (select (case when dayofweek(now()) = 7 then curdate() - interval 1 day
                   when dayofweek(now()) = 6 then curdate()
                   else dayofweek(now()) - interval dayofweek(now()) day
              end) as saturday
     ) x
where tl.ticketdate < x.saturday and
      tl.ticketdate >= x.saturday - interval 7 day
```

Comment: First of all thanks for help. But im getting error which says
`unknown table t` if i change it to `SELECT * FROM` it returns empty. I dont know i cant fix it.

Comment: This query select everyday except Fridays :D

Comment: @Gunsela92 . . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle?